# undefined reference in ffmpeg (use code blocks)

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, codeblocks

I am currently testing a video encoding program using ffmepg codeblocks.I encountered several undefined reference warning. I have checked on internet and add extern "c" to the headers but it still doesnt work. Please help me check.

Here is part of the code:

```
extern "C" {

#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavutil/channel_layout.h"
#include "libavutil/common.h"
#include "libavutil/imgutils.h"
#include "libavutil/mathematics.h"
#include "libavutil/samplefmt.h"


}

#include <math.h>
#include "libavutil/opt.h"

static void video_encode_example(const char *filename, int codec_id)
{

AVCodec *codec;
AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
int i, ret, x, y, got_output;
FILE *f;
AVFrame *frame;
AVPacket pkt;
uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };
printf("Encode video file %s\n", filename);
/* find the mpeg1 video encoder */
codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
if (!codec) {
fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
exit(1);
}
c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
if (!c) {
fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
avcodec_register_all();
video_encode_example("test.mpg", AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO);

return 0;
}
```

The error given:

||=== Build: Debug in ffmepg_video_en (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `video_encode_example':|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|36|undefined reference to`avcodec_find_encoder'|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|41|undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_context3'|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|63|undefined reference to`av_opt_set(void*, char const*, char const*, int)'|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|65|undefined reference to `avcodec_open2'|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|74|undefined reference to`av_frame_alloc'|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|85|undefined reference to `av_image_alloc(unsigned char**, int*, int, int, AVPixelFormat, int)'|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|92|undefined reference to`av_init_packet'|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|112|undefined reference to `avcodec_encode_video2'|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|120|undefined reference to`av_free_packet'|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|126|undefined reference to `avcodec_encode_video2'|
/home/yonghao/codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|134|undefined reference to`av_free_packet'|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|140|undefined reference to `avcodec_close'|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|141|undefined reference to`av_free'|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|142|undefined reference to `av_freep'|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|143|undefined reference to`av_frame_free'|
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `main':|
codeblocksfile/ffmepg_video_en/main.cpp|151|undefined reference to`avcodec_register_all'|
||=== Build failed: 16 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|

Comment: This is a link error - you need to set your library dependencies.

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/

Comment: Thank you. As I added the lib and include to the codeblocks, the original error disappear but some new error appear.